# RIPEMD-160 file digest

Tags: command-line, hashsum, cryptography

How can I make a file digest under Linux with the RIPEMD-160 hash function, from the command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `openssl` for that (and for other hash algorithms):

```
 $ openssl list-message-digest-commands
md4
md5
mdc2
rmd160
sha
sha1

 $ openssl rmd160 /usr/bin/openssl 
RIPEMD160(/usr/bin/openssl)= 788e595dcadb4b75e20c1dbf54a18a23cf233787
```